# Save to Downloads folder, DataWriter.FlushAsync hangs for 90 seconds

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, windows-runtime

The code:

```
private async Task<int> Save()
{
    StorageFile file = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("a.exe");
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    writer.WriteBytes(buffer);
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    await writer.FlushAsync();    //Hang for a long time
    writer.Dispose();
    return 1001;  //eventually it can get to this line, no exception is thrown
}
```

**Edit:**

It is found on Win8 CP build 8250, after upgraded to build 8375, the problem goes away. So I guess it is a bug that have been fixed either in winrt or win8.

Comment: I call this method from the handler for a button's click event.

Comment: And the OS version is Windows 8 Consumer Preview, build 8250.

Comment: Are you doing this on a background thread?  That can lead to hangs when calling async winrt apis

Comment: @RobertLevy It is called from the UI thread, like this `private void btnClick(object sender, someEventArgs e) { Save(); }`

Comment: Try writing a file with a different extension .txt for example and also, do you really need to call FlushAsync?

Comment: @Slugart It does not help to use a different extension. `FlushAsync` is called in order to save the contents to the disk, the file will be an empty file with 0 Byte without this call.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something more like this:

```
using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outStream))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer)
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
        }

        await outStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```